# How to populate data from a range (multiple rows and columns) to listbox with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with how to put the data from the range with multiple columns and rows to a listbox.

Assume I have a range rng which multiple columns and rows
I tried:

[image]

If I tried addItem rng(i,j) then everything would be in 1 column.

I also tried .list but it did not work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long
    Dim Myarray() As String

    '~~> Change your sheetname here
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Set you relevant range here
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:E5")

    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count

        ReDim Myarray(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

        rw = 0

        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            For j = 0 To rng.Columns.Count
                Myarray(rw, j) = rng.Cells(i, j + 1)
            Next
            rw = rw + 1
        Next

        .List = Myarray

        '~~> Set the widths of the column here. Ex: For 5 Columns
        '~~> Change as Applicable        
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50"
        .TopIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Yes Siddhart Rout. It is what I have tried for two days. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to populate 3 columns

```
Dim currRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
With Selection
For Each currRange In Range("yourRange")
        i = i + 1
        If i = 1 Then .AddItem cell.Value
        If i = 2 Then .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "1"
        If i = 3 Then
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            i = 0
        End If
Next
End With
```

I am assuming you have 3 columns.

Comment: Thank you very much Sudhakar, it depends on the the range - that why I count the columns and rows of the range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach to add items to the list box

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("lstSample").Select

Dim currRange As Range
With Selection
    For Each currRange In Range("yourRange")
        .AddItem currRange.Value
    Next
End With
```

For each itself iterates through each row and column in your range.

Comment: I would like to have multiple columns listbox. Your only make all data to 1 column