# VBA Excel Populate ListBox with multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

This may be a cheap question for some but I'm totally confused on how to populate my listbox.

[image: form with listbox]

Using this line I can populate the listbox as shown below:
    `ListBox1.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value`

or

```
Dim rngName As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then Me.ListBox1.AddItem 
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
```

[image: form with listbox 1 column output]

Below is the data I'm planning to use to populate the list box and is progressive. Only the column has the fix count. 
[image: Data]

Someone please enlighten me on how to populate a list box adapative to multiple columns and rows using **FOR LOOP** as shown in my code above. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763310/how-to-populate-data-from-a-range-multiple-rows-and-columns-to-listbox-with-vb)

Comment: And for non contiguous range see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621758/excel-vba-multicollumn-listbox-add-non-contiguous-range)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Those line includes declaring certain range. Is it possible to use the range of all cells that are not blank cell?

Comment: Why do you *want* to loop? It's much faster not to.

Comment: Can you not use dynamic named ranges?

Comment: Also, if you have a lookup table as shown, don't you need only one drop down and the others auto-populate unless you want update functionality?

Comment: Because the data is progressive. It is not fixed. Everytime the user inputs data, it adds up to the listbox. Hope someone can understand my point :(

Comment: How to auto populate this listbox? My mind is clouded for hours on finding how to do this one including update functionality.

Comment: @MarkJaysonVillanueva `myArray = Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value` will create an array. Using `ListBox1.List = myArray` you can populate listbox.

Comment: @Rory Thank you for telling me that. Can you enlighten me to another approach on how to auto populate the listbox without using static named ranges?

Comment: @AntiDrondert 1 column only I guess? I'm stuck on populating list box inluding more than 1 column.

Comment: @AntiDrondert man can you help me? What you give may lead me where I should be heading.

Comment: @MarkJaysonVillanueva `Set myRange = Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)` , `ListBox1.ColumnCount = myRange.Columns.Count` , `myArray = myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value` , `ListBox1.List = myArray` something like this.. I guess? I didn't test it though. If list turns up to be sideways (for some reason), use `Application.Transpose(myArray)` before assigning it to listbox's list.

Comment: @MarkJaysonVillanueva Acualy meant `Set myRange = Range("A1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`, forgot it isn't just one column anymore.

Comment: @AntiDrondert I'm getting run-time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @MarkJaysonVillanueva duh, which line? Is it `Set myRange = Range("A1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)` or the one with `ListBox1`?

Comment: @AntiDrondert yes. I put break on that line but I declare that already.

Comment: @Serversta Does it throw an error nonetheless? Or did you fix it already? Does the code work as intended?

Comment: @AntiDrondert It's throwing error still the same. I declared all the variable from the code you give me.

Comment: I said dynamic named range. It is dynamic not static. This would also allow for lookup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Methods**

1. It's always better to loop through an array than a range - it's **much faster**.
2. It's even faster to create a variant data field array with a **one liner** instead of redimensioning a predeclared array and fill it in an extra loop as proposed by Siddharth Rout (though a good method :-) *Note:* The code below is based on his Approach referenced in the above comment just to demonstrate the difference.
3. Fill `ListBox1.List` with the array (same method, but reverse direction).

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Purpose:  fill listbox with range values after clicking on CommandButton1
'           (code could be applied to UserForm_Initialize(), too)
' Note:     based on @Siddharth-Rout 's proposal at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763310/how-to-populate-data-from-a-range-multiple-rows-and-columns-to-listbox-with-vb
'           but creating a variant data field array directly from range in a one liner
'           (instead of filling a redimensioned array with range values in a loop)
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim rng     As Range
Dim MyArray                 ' variant, receives one based 2-dim data field array
'~~> Change your sheetname here
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'~~> Set you relevant range here
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count

    '~~> create a one based 2-dim datafield array
     MyArray = rng

    '~~> fill listbox with array values
    .List = MyArray

    '~~> Set the widths of the column here. Ex: For 5 Columns
    '~~> Change as Applicable
    .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"
    .TopIndex = 0
End With
End Sub
```

**Additional hints**

- Another advantage of the array method - it *overcomes* the built-in limitation of only **10 columns** when using the `.AddItem` method.
- Furthermore, keep in mind that listbox indexing is *zero based*, so for example you get the  e-mail address (column 3, index 2) of your first item row (index 0) via `ListBox1.List(0, 2)`, whereas the data field array becomes automatically a one based 2-dim array.
- You aren't restricted to use the `.List` method to get Information out of the listbox, you can reverse the row - column order by using `ListBox1.Column" or even create a new array out of it, which remains a 2-dim object, even if there is only ONE item (note: the`Application.Transpose` method would redim a 2 dimensional array with only one row to a 1-dim array).
- A last point: you can easily dump back again the whole listbox to an Excel sheet via `rng = ListBox1.List`, but take care to define the correct range.

Comment: I am grateful for the positive learning environment you provided me with. I learned that the approach you'd given me was better!

Comment: Glad I could help, see some additional hints in my edit.

Comment: when loading a lstbox like this, is it possible to marke certain columns as hidden (like the id columns i have in my multi-dimensional arrray)

Comment: @mike01010 Sounds like a new question. Assigning a datafield array always refers to the values in adjacent cells or columns in a given base range; if you want to exclude/omit some columns in the datafield array itself you'd have to either rearrange it like shown e.g. in [moving columns based on header name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822542/moving-columns-based-on-header-name) or to build a new one via array loop or to use the newer dynamic Excel functions to write to a temp sheet. Personally I'd simply set the hidden ColumnWidths to 0; if id is the 1st col just change the rng def.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
Sub foo()
Dim rngName As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ListBox1.Clear
ListBox1.columnCount = 3
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then ListBox1.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then ListBox1.List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value <> vbNullString Then ListBox1.List(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to help me. I do appreciate it!