# How to exclude columns by name when importing multiple xml-files to Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, import, dynamic-columns

I have managed to make a macro which imports multiple xml-files to excel, in individual tables. The problem is that some of the tables includes one extra column. I want the column names to be in the same column for all tables.

I am using VBA and I do not have that much experience with this.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
    xCount = 1
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)
        xWb.Close False
        xCount = xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save

On Error Resume Next
Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    Exit Sub


ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files xml", , "Kutools for Excel"

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you identify the extra column? Does it have the same caption? Is it at a fixed position?

Comment: I need to identify it by column name. The position is not fixed since the additional column for one of the xml-files showed up in the middle of the table in excel.

Comment: But the the name of this extra column is always the same?

Comment: yes, it is :)))

Comment: In addition, I the output shows headers in row 1 for the first xml-file. Further, I get headers for the second xml-file underneath without any space between the tables. For example: table for xml1 has headers in row 1 and data from r2 to r5. the table for xml2 has headers in row 6 and data from r7 to r11, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you delete the extra column in the source sheet before you copy the data. As you close the file after the copy without saving, it shouldn't be a problem.

Note that when you delete something, you should always do it from the end to the start.

```
Dim startRow As Long
startRow = 1
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
    With xWb.Sheets(1)
        Dim lastCol As Long, col As Long
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' Loop over all columns from right to left 
        For col = lastCol To 1 Step -1
            ' Throw the extra column away
            If .Cells(1, col) = "YourUnwantedCol" Then
                .Cells(1, col).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next col

        ' Now copy the data 
        .UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(startRow, 1)
        startRow = startRow + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ' Close without saving, don't show a warning.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xWb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        xFile = Dir()
    End With
Loop
```

Comment: Helpful & easy +1) - FYI another approach to flexibilize target columns -  [moving columns based on header name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822542/moving-columns-based-on-header-name/56778630#56778630) - @FunThomas

Comment: Was thinking about something like that, but preferred to loop over all columns as this makes it easier to adapt when the logic how to identify the unwanted column(s) changes.

Comment: The logic in the cited answer identifies the *wanted* columns, so you get no problem with any *unwanted* one. - @FunThomas BTW You wrote a perfect & clever answer, in any case for less experienced users.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I will try this out now. But how should I link this to my current code?

Comment: I need to delete this column for every xml-file I am importing. So I am guessing I need to implement it in my current loop?

Comment: Yes. Look at my code: It contains already the loop. Just C&P it to replace your `Do While`-Loop

Comment: hmm, I get the same output as before.

Comment: Debug your code and check why the column is not removed. Have you adapted the name of the column you want to delete?

Comment: Yup, I have adapted the name of the column. I used the exact name I got from the output. Check my answer below with the updated code.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you any further with this. As I said, debug the code and check why the column is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
    xCount = 1
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")



    Dim startRow As Long
startRow = 1
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
    With xWb.Sheets(1)
        Dim lastCol As Long, col As Long
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' Loop over all columns from right to left
        For col = lastCol To 1 Step -1
            ' Throw the extra column away
            If .Cells(1, col) = "Content" Then
                .Cells(1, col).EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next col

        ' Now copy the data
        .UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(startRow, 1)
        startRow = startRow + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ' Close without saving, don't show a warning.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xWb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        xFile = Dir()
    End With
Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save

'Removes rows with no "event id"
On Error Resume Next
Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Exit Sub


ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files xml", , "Kutools for Excel"

End Sub
```