# reorder columns vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Sorry I can not find were I got this code

The code Reorders columns base on a list of all column in a sheet

It works fast on a large number of columns, but it requires that you list ALL columns in your sheet if you do not it deletes the columns not listed

There are Copy-paste versions of this but they are very slow and not suited to a large number of columns

> I only want to list the columns I want to be **reordered** to the *beginning of the sheet*, all *other columns left in the order they were in* after the reordered listed columns

Have had no luck doing this

Thanks

```
Sub colOrder()
' Purpose: restructure range columns
With Sheet1                                               ' worksheet referenced e.g. via CodeName

' [0] identify range
  Dim rng As Range, lastRow&, lastCol&
  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row        ' get last row and last column
  lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~
' [1] get data
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Dim v: v = rng                                        ' assign to 1-based 2-dim datafield array

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' [2] restructure column order in array in a one liner
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  v = Application.Index(v, Evaluate("row(1:" & lastRow & ")"), getColNums(v))

' [3] write data back to sheet
  rng = vbNullString                                    ' clear orginal data
  .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v      ' write new data

End With

End Sub
```

**Helper function called by above main procedure**

The helper function simply returns an array with the correct column numbers found in the current titles; it uses `Application.Match` to find currencies:

```
Function getColNums(arr) As Variant()
' Purpose: return array of found column number order, e.g. Array(3,2,1,4,6,5)
Dim colOrdr(), titles                                           ' wanted order, current titles
colOrdr = Array("id", "last_name", "first_name", "gender", "email", "ip_address") 'define column order with header names here
titles = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 1, 0)))

Dim i&, ii&, pos                                                ' array counters, element position
ReDim tmp(0 To UBound(colOrdr))                                 ' temporary array to collect found 
positions
For i = 0 To UBound(colOrdr)                                    ' loop through titles in wanted order
    pos = Application.Match(colOrdr(i), titles, 0)              ' check positions
    If Not IsError(pos) Then tmp(ii) = pos: ii = ii + 1         ' remember found positions, increment 
counter
Next I
ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To ii - 1)                                 ' remove empty elements
getColNums = tmp                                                ' return array with current column 
numbers (1-based)
End Function
```

Comment: Power Query / Get & Transform does this quite well.

Comment: You can use `Range.Find` for your array loop and just `Cut/Paste` when found. This will make sure nothing gets deleted if not in your array

Comment: If I use Copy-Paste it becomes to slow for a large number of columns

Comment: *Sorry I cannot find where I got this code*: see [Moving columns based on header name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822542/moving-columns-based-on-header-name/56778630#56778630) answered Jun 26 '19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rearranging columns due to title list**

> *"I only want to list the columns I want to be reordered to the beginning of the sheet all other columns left in the order they were in after the reordered listed columns"*

It suffices

1. to add an (optional) 2nd **argument** `DeleteRest`to the help function `getColNums`,
2. to insert a **negative filtering** routine in `a)` to get the remaining titles (array `rest`) and
3. to insert a conditional code block `b)` executing the argument's *"order"* passed by default **not** to delete unlisted titles

```
    If Not DeleteRest Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(rest)
            pos = Application.Match(rest(i), titles, 0)             ' check positions
            If Not IsError(pos) Then
                tmp(ii) = pos: ii = ii + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
```

*(and you could leave the calling procedure `ColOrder` unchanged - see section **`[2]`**)*

**Modified help function `getColNums()`**

Only in case that the 2nd argument `DeleteRest` (which is `False` by default) will be passed intently as `True` each *unlisted* column would now be removed. Otherwise there's no more need to list the entire title set to prevent deletion.

```
Function getColNums(arr, Optional ByVal DeleteRest As Boolean = False) As Variant()
' Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918751/reorder-columns-vba
' Purp: return array of found column number order, e.g. Array(3,2,1,4,6,5)
' Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
' Date: 2020-05-25
' Note: if argument DeleteRest (default: False) is passed as True, each unlisted titles will be removed
Dim colOrdr(), titles                                           ' wanted order, current titles
colOrdr = Array("id", "last_name", "first_name", "gender", "email", "ip_address") 'define column order with header names here
titles = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, 1, 0)))
Dim rest: rest = titles
Dim i&, ii&, pos                                                ' array counters, element position
ReDim tmp(0 To UBound(colOrdr) + UBound(titles) + 2)            ' temporary array to collect found positions
' a) find position in
For i = 0 To UBound(colOrdr)                                    ' loop through titles in wanted order
    pos = Application.Match(colOrdr(i), titles, 0)              ' check positions
    If Not IsError(pos) Then
        tmp(ii) = pos: ii = ii + 1                              ' remember found positions, increment counter
        rest = Filter(rest, colOrdr(i), False, vbTextCompare)
    End If
Next i
' b) Default: ~~~> don't remove unlisted titles  <~~~           ' << inserted code block as of 2020-05-15 >>
If Not DeleteRest Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(rest)
        pos = Application.Match(rest(i), titles, 0)             ' check positions
        If Not IsError(pos) Then
            tmp(ii) = pos: ii = ii + 1
        End If
    Next i
End If

ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To ii - 1)                                 ' remove empty elements
getColNums = tmp                                                ' return array with current column numbers (1-based)
Debug.Print Join(tmp, "|") & " ... " & Join(rest, "|")
End Function
```

**Related link**

I listed some pecularities of the `Application.Index` function at [Insert first column in datafield array without loops or API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: Thank you T.M. the addition of the boolean argument is great