# Change header row and return last 3 characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently reorganizing some columns using VBA code and I need to make a change to one of the header rows and the values in 1 specific column. I've included what I'm basically trying to do in a comment. Here is the code I'm using but very cut down for brevity.

```
Sub columnOrder2()
Dim search As Range
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim colOrdr As Variant
Dim indx As Integer

colOrdr = Array("User name", "LanID", "Asset Tag")
cnt = 1


For indx = LBound(colOrdr) To UBound(colOrdr)
    Set search = Rows("1:1").Find(colOrdr(indx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
   ' If search = "LanID" then change header row to "Last3"
   ' and return only the last 3 characters for values in cells
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        If search.Column <> cnt Then
            search.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
Next indx
End Sub
```

Currently, I'm just running the code and manually renaming the column then creating a formula in cell g2  and using `=Right(G2,3)` and copying it down to the rest of the cells in column C. I know VBA can do this much better and maybe even just in a separate function. Any help would be appreciated. I haven't worked with Excel VBA for awhile now.

Comment: It's not clear if you refer to column C or C plus G. - Did you mean to overwrite the `LANId` column with its own last three char values? - Posted an approach that could be modified easily in any case @MattWilliamson :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean to overwrite the `LANId` column with its own last three characters, you could code as follows (`C2` instead of `G2` in your question?):

**Modified code close to OP**

*Includes a fully qualified (worksheet) range reference, btw* (as otherwise VBA assumes any currently active worksheet) :-)

```
Sub columnOrder2()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1   ' << Using e.g. the sheet's Code(Name)
Dim colOrdr As Variant
colOrdr = Array("User name", "LanID", "Asset Tag")
Dim cnt     As Long
cnt = 1
Dim indx    As Long
For indx = LBound(colOrdr) To UBound(colOrdr)
    Dim search  As Range
    Set search = ws.Rows("1:1").Find(colOrdr(indx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
    
        If LCase(search.Text) = "lanid" Then
            'set column range object to memory
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = getColRange(ws, search.Column, Startrow:=1)
            'return only the last 3 characters
            rng.Value = Evaluate("=Right(" & rng.Address & ",3)")
            'change header cell from "LANId" to "Last3"
            rng(1, 1) = "Last3"     ' change header from LANId to Last3
        End If
        
        If search.Column <> cnt Then
            search.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(cnt).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
Next indx

End Sub
```

**Help function**

Returns the range of a given sheet column up to the last row with a value:

```
Function getColRange(mySheet As Worksheet, _
                     Optional ByVal myColumn As Variant = "A", _
                     Optional ByVal Startrow As Long = 1) As Range
With mySheet
'a) change numeric column number to letter(s)
    If IsNumeric(myColumn) Then myColumn = Split((.Columns(myColumn).Address(, 0)), ":")(0)
'b) get last row in given column
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range(myColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'c) return data range as function result
'   (a Range is an Object and has to be SET!)
    Set getColRange = .Range(myColumn & Startrow & ":" & myColumn & lastRow)
End With
End Function
```

**Related link**

Instead of moving entire columns one after the other you might be interested in an array approach - c.f. [Delete an array column and change position of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664086/delete-an-array-column-and-change-position-of-two-columns/62666087#62666087)

Comment: This is great code @T.M. I did come up with a different approach but similar. I do have a quick question if you don't mind. Is `rng.Value = Evaluate("=Right(" & rng.Address & ",3)")` better than using the VBA Right function? The way I did it was to use `Cells(i, 3).Value = Right(Cells(i, 3), 3)` but in a loop with just a small amount of data. It takes about 5 seconds to run. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MattWilliamson Appreciate your reply -  Using VBA I prefer a either (1) a solution in one go as above (at least if I can avoid looping over range references) or (2) by looping through an array (could also be via `VBA.Right()`). It's not so much a question whether a VBA or Excel  function per se be better (`Evaluate()` uses indirectly the Excel function `RIGHT()`), but more a question of conception (e.g. is it necessary to move entire columns, have I to do this repeatedly etc :-) Another link: [Reorder columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918751/reorder-columns-vba/62010304#62010304)