# Rearrange columns on excel sheet by header based on the order of a different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rearrange the columns of sheet1 based on the order of a different workbook called export. For example, the headers of export are Code, Type, Color (in cells a1, b1, c1). Here is my sheet 1:

```
| Color| Code | Type |
| A    | C    | E    |
| B    | D    | F    |
```

I need this to become:

```
| Code | Type    | Color |
| C    | E       | A     |
| D    | F       | B     |
```

The letters here just represent how the below data needs to be rearranged as well, not just the column headers. I need this to work for the first 6 columns on the sheet, but the remaining columns should be left alone.

I am new to vba and have been trying to use the range.find function to find the index of my column header and copy it, but I'm unsure how to just have it rearrange instead of copying to a new sheet entirely. I know that my reference workbook (export) will be in the same windows folder and I know how to access it. If this question has been answered, please link me, thank you!

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823850/478884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rearrange Columns According to Columns in Another Workbook

**Source**

[image]

**Destination - Before**

[image]

**Destination - After**

[image]

---

```vb
Sub RearrangeColumns()
     
    ' Define constants.
     
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = "Export.xlsx"
    Const SRC_SHEET_ID As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_HEADER_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "C3"
    Const NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS As Long = 6
    Const DST_SHEET_ID As Variant = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_HEADER_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "D4"
    
    ' Store the folder path in a variable.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = dwb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    ' Open the source workbook and reference the source headers.

    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & SRC_FILE_NAME)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_ID)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws _
        .Range(SRC_FIRST_HEADER_CELL_ADDRESS).Resize(, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
     
    ' Reference the destination headers.
     
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_ID)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws _
        .Range(DST_FIRST_HEADER_CELL_ADDRESS).Resize(, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
    
    ' Return the destination column indexes in an array.
    
    Dim dfCol As Long: dfCol = drg.Column
    Dim dcIndices() As Variant: dcIndices = Application.Match(srg, drg, 0)
    
    ' Close the source workbook.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False  ' it was just read from
    
    ' Return the destination single-column references in another array.
    
    Dim dRanges() As Range: ReDim dRanges(1 To NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
    
    Dim dcIndex As Variant, c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
        If IsNumeric(dcIndices(c)) Then
            Set dRanges(c) = dws.Columns(dcIndices(c) + dfCol - 1)
        End If
    Next c
    
    ' Rearrange i.e. move all columns to the left of the first.
    
    For c = NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS To 1 Step -1
        If Not dRanges(c) Is Nothing Then
            dRanges(c).Cut
            dws.Columns(dfCol).Insert
        End If
    Next c
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Columns rearranged.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim arr2, i As Long, c As Range
    Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' Load header form Sheet2
    arr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").[a1].CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr2, 2)
        ' Loop through header in Sheet1
        For Each c In Sht1.[a1].CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Cells
            If c.Value = arr2(1, i) Then ' Header match
                If c.Column <> i Then
                    c.EntireColumn.Cut
                    Sht1.Columns(i).Insert
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
End Sub
```