# populate VBA list box from row source and update multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

i am trying to populate VBA userform listbox with below code. It works if i select range from A to F column. however if i change A to L, it gives me an error.

can you help me to correct below code?

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("part bump")

    Dim Last_Row As Long
    Dim r, c As Range

    Last_Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

    With UserForm3
       
        .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 11
        .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
        .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "20,40,40,40,2,60,60,60,60,300,60"
        
        Set r = sh.Range("A4:F" & Last_Row)
     
        i = 0
        For Each d In r.Rows
            j = 0
            For Each c In d.Cells
                UserForm3.lstDatabase.AddItem
     
                UserForm3.lstDatabase.List(i, j) = c.Value
                j = j + 1
     
            Next c
            i = i + 1
        Next d
     
        If Last_Row = 1 Then
            UserForm3.lstDatabase.RowSource = "part bump!A4:F4"
        
        End If
        
    End With
```

Below code use to update multiple selected rows under userform. it only updates 1st selected row not all selected rows.

```
    Private Sub cmdaction_Click()
    Dim t, t1 As String
  Dim vrech As Range, lColumn As Range
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Dim selItem As String
  
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("part bump")
  Set lColumn = sh.Range("H1:AZA1").Find(Val(txtchangenumber.Value), , xlValues, xlWhole)
  If lColumn Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column not found"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  
  With UserForm3.lstDatabase
    For i = 0 To UserForm3.lstDatabase.ListCount - 1
    
      If UserForm3.lstDatabase.Selected(i) = True Then
        Set vrech = sh.Range("E3:E250").Find(.Column(4, i), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not vrech Is Nothing Then
          Select Case cmbaction.Value
            Case "RP"
              t = Chr(Asc(Mid(.List(i, 4), 2, 1)) + 1)
              'Me.lstDatabase.Row (0), Column(4) = "ABA"
              t1 = Mid(.List(i, 4), 1, 1) & t & Mid(.List(i, 4), 3, 1)
              Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = t1
          Case "RV"
            Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = .List(i, 4)
          Case "DP"
            Intersect(vrech.EntireRow, lColumn.EntireColumn) = "Deleted"
            vrech.EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
          End Select
        End If
      End If
      
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Populate Listbox**

It's not clear for me whether you want to assign range data

- **a)** via the listbox'es `.RowSource` property (showing headers) or
- **b)** via the listbox'es `.List` property (allowing no headers)

I demonstrate both approaches modifying your original code.

Furthermore I suggest to move your code into the form's own code module - the `UserForm_Initialize` handler would be a good place for this.
C.f.

**Version a)**

Note that you have to include a blank delimited sheet name (`part bump`) within "'", e.g. via

```
.RowSource = "'part bump'!A4:L17"
```

or

```
.RowSource = "'" & sh.Name & "'!" & rng.Address
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("part bump")
    
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 3
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow = HeaderRow Then LastRow = HeaderRow + 1 ' provide for empty data
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.Range("A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":L" & LastRow)
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    
    With lstDatabase
        .ColumnCount = 11
        .ColumnWidths = "20;40;40;40;2;60;60;60;60;300;60"
        
        'a) Row Source plus headers
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "'" & sh.Name & "'!" & rng.Address   ' << don't forget "'" around sheet name!

    End With
    
End Sub
```

**Version b)**

> *"It works if i select range from A to F column. however if i change A to L, it give me an error."*

Adding data via the `.AddItem` method has a not documented limitation of **10 columns only**
(these are provided automatically as empty array items of the `.List` property).
Therefore it's not possible to reference a (zero-based) column index of 10 or more as it doesn't exist.

You can shorten your code and overcome this limitation by assigning an entire data field array to the listbox'es `.List` property.
c.f.: [Populate listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528558/vba-excel-populate-listbox-with-multiple-columns/47531440#47531440)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("part bump")
    
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 3
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow = HeaderRow Then LastRow = HeaderRow + 1 ' provide for empty data
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.Range("A" & HeaderRow + 1 & ":L" & LastRow)
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    
    With lstDatabase
        .ColumnCount = 11
        .ColumnWidths = "20;40;40;40;2;60;60;60;60;300;60"
        
        'b) alternatively via array assignment (without headers!)
        '   allows to overcome 10 column limitation of .AddItem
        .ColumnHeads = False

        .List = rng.Value   ' << assign data field array as a whole to .List
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**Further hint**

Your declaration in OP (`Dim r, c As Range`) intends to declare a `Range` data type to both variables,
but it fails as VBA assumes `Variant` for `r` if not declare expressly (`Dim r as Range, c As Range`).

Comment: thanks for detail response. This helps me to understand listbox row source. both codes works as intended. with version A, when i try to update multiple rows under multiselect listbox, it only changes 1st selected row. can you pl help me to modify code so i am able to update multiple rows with version one as i need to have header.              thanks

Comment: My solution assumes your header row in row 3, if not you should change the definition `Const HeaderRow As Long = 3` to the actual row number. A working header functionality via `.RowSource` always defines the data range to start one row below header. Did you write `UserForm_Initialize` into the form's code module? Plz re-check the code. - @jay6939

Comment: Thanks for feedback. with version A. listbox populate with Header from Row 3 and list populate from row 4 of row source. it works as intented. when i try to update multiple rows under listbox, it only updates 1st selected row and not all selected rows. i am using below code to update multiple rows with command button,

Comment: I have updated initial post with code i am using to update multiple rows under listbox. can you pl help to find where i am making mistake?

Comment: @jay6939 Glad that *"it works as intended"*. If helpful feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark. It's good use at SO to pose *another* question if you have *another* issue and not to expand the original post. It would be helpful to add some data to such a new question describing what you want to update by example :-)