# listbox to show multiple column data

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, initialization, userform

How to get listbox to show data from a set range instead of active sheet?

```
Private Sub UserForm_INITIALIZE()
 With ListBox1

        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50"
        .RowSource = Sheet3.Range("B2:C21").Address
    End With
end sub
```

Comment: Your code work for me --- it populates Listbox1 with the contents of B2:C21. What problem are you having?

Comment: it is populating info from the active sheet. i need it to populate from sheet3 no matter what sheet is active.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Dim Data As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;50"
Data = Sheet3.Range("b2:c" & lastrow)
ListBox1.List = Data
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50"
        .RowSource = "Sheet3!B2:C21"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The code runs for me. I can't reproduce the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.List` instead of `.RowSource`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50"
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:C21").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**What is causing the active sheet reference?**

Using the `Address` property - though explicitly addressing the project's Sheet (Code)Name `Sheet3`

```
    .RowSource = Sheet3.Range("B2:C21").Address
```

will only assign the cells' range address "$B$2:$C$21", not the tabular worksheet reference.

To get the full reference `Sheet3!B2:C21` you could either set the `External` **argument** to `True` via

```
Sheet3.Range("A1:B7").Address(False,False,External:=True)
```

or prefix the range address string by the worksheet `Name` plus `!`

```
Sheet3.Name & "!" & Tabelle1.Range("A1:B7").Address(False,False)
```

**Further issue**

As you mentioned *Error 70 ("permission denied")*, it's very likely that you have further
code trying to add rows to the listbox'es `.List` property which doesn't get on well together.

Personally I'd do without `.RowSource` at all and handle the listbox list via [array assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528558/vba-excel-populate-listbox-with-multiple-columns/47531440#47531440)  or use an intermediate hidden sheet with rowsource data you can manipulate.

.