# Select a Value from Form ListBox and Show Value Associated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of items and descriptions in column A. The first item is in the 5th row. Each item is followed by the item description.

It looks something like the following (different, but the same concept):

```
Apple
Red Fruit
Banana
Yellow Fruit
```

What I am trying to do is put these both into 2 arrays based on whether it's an item or the description.

I've done that here:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub main()

    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim strNetId As String
    Dim strListArray() As String

    Set rngList = Sheets("data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Call CreateArray(rngList, strListArray())
    Call CreateArray2(rngList, strListArray())

End Sub

Sub CreateArray(rngIn As Range, strArray() As String)

    Dim iCols As Integer
    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim iRowsH As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Counter2 As Integer
    Dim Count2 As Integer        

    iRows = (rngIn.Rows.Count - 1)
    iCols = 1
    iRowsH = (rngIn.Rows.Count - 1) / 2

    ReDim strArray(iRows, iCols)

    Count2 = 3
    Counter = 1

    Do
        If Count2 Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            strArray(Counter, 1) = rngIn.Cells(Count2 + 2, 1)
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
        Count2 = Count2 + 1
    Loop Until Count2 > iRows

End Sub

Sub CreateArray2(rngIn2 As Range, strArray2() As String)

    Dim iCols As Integer
    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim iRowsH As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Counter2 As Integer
    Dim Count2 As Integer       

    iRows = (rngIn2.Rows.Count - 1)
    iCols = 1
    iRowsH = (rngIn2.Rows.Count - 1) / 2       

    ReDim strArray2(iRows, iCols)

    Count2 = 3
    Counter = 1

    Do
        If Count2 Mod 2 = 0 Then
            strArray2(Counter, 1) = rngIn2.Cells(Count2 + 2, 1)
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
        Count2 = Count2 + 1
    Loop Until Count2 > iRows

End Sub
```

Where I'm running into a problem is getting my form to work. What I want to happen is you start the form and then click one of the items that will be populated in the ListBox. Then a text box will pull up the associated description. Here's what I have in my form's code, but I'm getting an error when you actually select the item from the form:

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit
Dim strArray2()


Private Sub btnDone_Click()
    Unload frmNetID
End Sub    

Private Sub lstNetID_Click()
    lblFirstName.Caption = strArray2(lstNetID.ListIndex + 2, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim strNetId As String
    Dim strList() As String
    Dim iR As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
        iR = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        Set rngList = .Range("A1:A" & iR) 'it assumes header row
        Call CreateArray(rngList, strList())            

    End With

    lstNetID.List() = strList()

End Sub
```

Where am I making the first mistake? I'm guessing it has something to do with the lblFirstName.Caption line of code.

Comment: Create multicolumn Listbox as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763310/how-to-populate-data-from-a-range-multiple-rows-and-columns-to-listbox-with-vb) and then you can retrieve the value using `lstNetID.List(lstNetID.ListIndex, 0)` and `lstNetID.List(lstNetID.ListIndex, 1)`

Comment: Is your list box populated?

Comment: Does your used range contain some other columns, except A:A?

Comment: The list box does populate with the items and EVERYTHING is in column A.

Comment: The reason I want to only have 1 column in the ListBox is that the descriptions are actually very very long and don't want that mess always appearing. I simplified it for the sake of this post. Think a box of Cereal and the Ingredient list as the description.

Answer (score 0):

You code can be simplified and more eficient, I think. Please, see how the necessary arrays can be a little differently built and used:

```
Private Sub testFillArrays()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrN As Variant, arrD As Variant
 Dim n As Long, d As Long, i As Long, arrGlob() As Variant
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'you will use Sheets("data")

   arr = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2 'base 1 array
   ReDim arrN(0 To UBound(arr, 2), 0 To Int(UBound(arr, 1) / 2)) '(0 based array)
   ReDim arrD(0 To UBound(arr, 2), 0 To Int(UBound(arr, 1) / 2))
   For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            arrN(0, n) = arr(i, 1): n = n + 1 ' fruit names array
        Else
            arrD(0, d) = arr(i, 1): d = d + 1 ' fruit colors array
        End If
   Next i
   ReDim Preserve arrN(0 To 1, 0 To n - 1) 'clear the last empty element
   ReDim Preserve arrD(0 To 1, 0 To d - 1)

   'arrN is the array to be load in the list box.
   arrGlob = Array(arrN, arrD) 'define the array of arrays
   i = lstNetID.ListIndex 
   Debug.Print arrGlob(0)(0, i), arrGlob(1)(0, i) 'and press Ctrl + G to see the result...
End Sub
```