# Creating Multi Column ListBox with Headers - Run Time Error '70' Permission Denied

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to add a range of data to a multicolumn listbox and at the point where i create my list box from the array i have built, i get the error: `Run Time Error '70' Permission Denied`

I have full read/write access and there shouldn't be reason why i am receiving this error. Here is my code:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim hits As Collection
    Dim hit As Variant
    Dim arrItems() As Variant
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New")
    
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    WireEnt.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 10
    WireEnt.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50"
        With Me.ListBox1
         .ColumnHeads = True
         .RowSource = "C2:L" & LastRow
        End With
    
    For i = 1 To 1
     For j = 1 To LastCol
        If ws.Cells(i, j) = "Date Wire Entered" Then
         a = j
         Exit For
        End If
     Next j
    Next i
    
    'Read values into an array
    v = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells(LastRow, a))
    
    'Find the target values
    Set hits = New Collection
     For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If v(i, a - 2) = "" Then hits.Add i
    Next
    
    
    'Populate the listbox array with the hit items
    If hits.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim arrItems(1 To hits.Count, 1 To UBound(v, 2))
        i = 1
            For Each hit In hits
                For j = 1 To 10
                 arrItems(i, j) = v(hit, j)
                Next
            i = i + 1
            Next
        Me.ListBox1.List = arrItems
    Else
        'There are not hits so clear the listbox
        Me.ListBox1.Clear
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

The line of code causing the error is:

```
Me.ListBox1.List = arrItems
```

Please help!

Comment: `Run Time Error '70' Permission Denied` Yes that is because you have already set the rowsource `.RowSource = "C2:L" & LastRow`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am trying to add the column headers to the list box with that line of code. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Add them to the array? I have answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763310/how-to-populate-data-from-a-range-multiple-rows-and-columns-to-listbox-with-vb) before

Comment: @SiddharthRout Right but your post has      '.ColumnHeads = False
So in reality  you aren't adding the headers, you are simply just using the source headers as the first row and that isn't what i was looking for...

Comment: @NatashaLeon Posted a systematic answer and several workarounds to your issues; feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark if helpful :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- The main issue is that the `.RowSource` property bound to a predefined range
  doesn't cooperate with dynamic array assignments. Therefore executing `Me.ListBox1.List = arrItems`
  conflicts with the diverging data range and will raise a `Run Time Error '70' Permission Denied`.

  A drawback doing without `.RowSource` is that you sacrifice the possibility to get `ColumnHeads` automatically.
- Don't refer to the UserForm's name in a form's code module behind, it suffices
  to either prefix the `Me` keyword (e.g. `Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount`) or
  to reference the control alone (e.g. by `ListBox1.ColumnCount`)
- To separate column entries, use semicolons (;) as list separators. So use

  ```
   Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50"
  ```

**Possible solutions**

- So one simple workaround would be to include the headers as first data row.
- Another method frequently used is to fill labels on top of the listbox needing some coding to define widths.
- A further method consists in using another listbox with header titles only above the listbox.
- Alternatively you could write the wanted data to another (hidden) range and refresh/redefine `.RowSource` each time.